# How to remove dictionary items in list based on values in string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, list, data-manipulation

I'm busy extracting data with python 2.7
So far I got a list with dictionaries as items.
For 2 days I cannot get any further with this.

Data:

```
list = [
    {
        'displayName': '#12',
        'timestamp': 1543588481684,
        'number': 12,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Configs \xbb Virtual Host #12'
    },
    {   
        'displayName': '#64',
        'timestamp': 1544432646765,
        'number': 64,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Configs \xbb Development Virtual Host Deploy #64'
    },
    {
        'displayName': '#15',
        'timestamp': 1544432258338,
        'number': 15,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Configs \xbb Virtual Host #15'
    },
    {   
        'displayName': '#61',
        'timestamp': 1554186520499,
        'number': 61,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Docker \xbb Configs Deploy \xbb release/1.0.0 #61'
    },
    {   
        'displayName': '#5',
        'timestamp': 1554274310468,
        'number': 5,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Docker \xbb Configs Deploy \xbb release/1.0.2 #5'
    },
    {   
        'displayName': '#1',
        'timestamp': 1554289674392,
        'number': 1,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Docker \xbb Configs Deploy \xbb release/1.0.3 #1'
    },
    {   
        'displayName': '#1',
        'timestamp': 1554290695120,
        'number': 1,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Docker \xbb Configs Deploy \xbb release/1.0.4 #1'
    },
    {   'displayName': '#1',
        'timestamp': 1554292855198,
        'number': 1,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Docker \xbb Configs Deploy \xbb release/1.0.5 #1'
    },
    {   
        'displayName': '#1',
        'timestamp': 1554381545158,
        'number': 1,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Docker \xbb Configs Deploy \xbb release/1.0.7 #1'
    },
    {   'displayName': '#2',
        'timestamp': 1554191277415,
        'number': 2,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Docker \xbb Configs Deploy \xbb tag/1.0.0 #2'
    },
    {   'displayName': '#6',
        'timestamp': 1554212133716,
        'number': 6,
        'result': 'FAILURE',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Docker \xbb Configs Deploy \xbb tag/1.0.1 #6'
    }
]
```

I want to remove the dictionary items in the list, where 'fullDisplayName' contains('hotfix','tag') But keep the last list item ( dictionary with the highest version value (hotfix/1.0.?)  ).

Expected Output:

```
list = [
    {
        'displayName': '#12',
        'timestamp': 1543588481684,
        'number': 12,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Configs \xbb Virtual Host #12'
    },
    {   
        'displayName': '#64',
        'timestamp': 1544432646765,
        'number': 64,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Configs \xbb Development Virtual Host Deploy #64'
    },
    {
        'displayName': '#15',
        'timestamp': 1544432258338,
        'number': 15,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Configs \xbb Virtual Host #15'
    },
    {   
        'displayName': '#1',
        'timestamp': 1554381545158,
        'number': 1,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Docker \xbb Configs Deploy \xbb release/1.0.7 #1'
    },
    {   'displayName': '#6',
        'timestamp': 1554212133716,
        'number': 6,
        'result': 'FAILURE',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Docker \xbb Configs Deploy \xbb tag/1.0.1 #6'
    }
]
```

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean that dict `contains('hotfix','tag')`?

Comment: updated that part. hope it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

1. look for desired keywords
2. check for higher versions
3. remove item if necessary

Pseudo code:

```
for item in list:
    if dictContainsKeyword(item, "hotfix") or dictContainsKeyword(item, "tag"):
        if listContainsNewerVersion(list, item):
            removeDictFromList(list, item)
```

For dictContainsKeyword, listContainsNewerVersion and removeDictFromList you need to choose an attribute of the dictionary, that has unique values. Or use a set of attributes to identify a single dictionary.

In listContainsNewerVersion you can iterate over the list and compare the dictionaries with given one.

EDIT: changed to for each loop to avoid problems with list iteration and removing objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below approach, not very efficient but it will solve your problem

```
>>> list1 = [i for i in list if 'tag' not in i['fullDisplayName']]
>>> list2 = [i for i in list if 'tag' in i['fullDisplayName']]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> newlist = sorted(list2, key=itemgetter('displayName'), reverse=True)
>>> list1.append(newlist[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
new_list = []
append_last = (0, None)
for index, obj in enumerate(list):
    if 'hotfix' in obj['fullDisplayName'] or 'tag' in obj['fullDisplayName']:
        number = int("tag/1.0.1".split('/')[1].replace('.',''))
        append_last = (number, index) if append_last[0] < number else append_last
    else:
        new_list.append(obj)
if append_last[1]:
    new_list.append(list[append_last[1]])
print new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming our original is called `my_list` and values we need to restrict are stored in `restricted`

```
my_list = [
    {
        'displayName': '#12',
        'timestamp': 1543588481684,
        'number': 12,
        'result': 'SUCCESS',
        'fullDisplayName': 'Configs \xbb Virtual Host #12'
    },
    ...
]
restricted = ['hotfix','tag']
```

First we need to find dictionary with highest number, we'll use [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) and set `key` to find dictionary based on highest value of `['number']`.

```
highest = max(my_list, key=lambda x: x['number'])
```

We could use python builtin function [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to filter out specific dictionaries. For that we will define function that will decide whether some dictionary is valid or not, here `my_filter()`.

```
def my_filter(x):
    # check if provided dict is one with the highest value
    if x == highest:
        return True

    # check if ['fullDisplayName'] doesn't contains any of resticted words
    if not any(i in x['fullDisplayName'] for i in restricted):
        return True

    return False

new_list = list(filter(my_filter, my_list))
```

---

Or with filter function as lambda in one line

```
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: x==highest or not any(i in x['fullDisplayName'] for i in restricted), my_list))
```